# I can't upgrade nodejs version from 10.24.0 to 14.16.1(LTS) on Raspberry Pi Desktop

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I installed Raspberry Pi Desktop on an old laptop and then I installed nodejs using 'sudo apt install nodejs'. After that, when I verify the version of node, using 'node -v' or 'nodejs -v' I get 'v10.24.0'.
Then I try upgrade the Nodejs version but it doesn't work because whatever way I used to upgrade, the version stays the same.

I try this:

```
    pi@local-server-raspi:~ $  sudo su -  
    root@local-server-raspi:~ # apt-get remove nodered -y  
    root@local-server-raspi:~ # apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy -y 
    root@local-server-raspi:~ # apt-get remove npm -y

    root@local-server-raspi:~ # curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -

    root@local-server-raspi:~ # apt-get install nodejs -y
    root@local-server-raspi:~ # node -v
    v10.24.0

    root@local-server-raspi:~ # npm -v
    bash: npm: command not found
```

I also try with nvm but with the same result, when I type 'nodejs -v' I get 'no such file or directory' and when I type 'node -v' I get the same version, 10.24.0.

I appreciate it if any of you have some idea how to upgrade the version of the nodejs to the LTS version, 14.16.1.

Comment: That's because apt will always get the version from Raspbian's repository, and as a rule linux distros don't make major version upgrades to components in the same release version, just fixes. You'll either need to find .deb files someone else has built with a later version, or find a repository of them that you can register with apt so that it knows where to find later versions, or you can build and install it yourself from source e.g. starting with the .deb source distribution and just upgrading the components within it. (It's much easier to find a pre-built one though if you can.)

Comment: You also don't need to replace the 'system' version from the distro: you could install a separate version in a separate path to run against when you need the latest. That's probably more important for libraries and tools that system components are built on though, to make sure you don't break anything, whereas I don't know of any common linux tool that's built with node.

Comment: Or if you can find a version of nvm (= node version manager) for Raspberry Pi that'd be a good place to start too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install nodejs to the raspberrypi 4. I needed a newer version to run yarn. There are many tutorials but this instruction video (below) fixed my problem and upgraded the nodejs to 14.16.1. (Thanks Dave!!!)
thisdavej.com/upgrading-to-more-recent-versions-of-node-js-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks! In general we prefer complete answers here not just links to answers elsewhere: could you please edit your answer to include the general steps or approach too please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Raspberry Pi3. I tried all sorts of things and this is what finally worked...

```
node -v
v10.24.0

# Remove...
sudo apt remove node
sudo apt remove nodejs

# Install...
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Check
node -v && npm -v
v14.19.3
6.14.17
```

Comment: That's pretty much the steps in the question though, which didn't work for OP. But glad it worked for you!